# ASP.NET MVC 4 Website Deployment Error 404 - Application Name Missed in URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, deployment, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

I have looked in this site and seen some discussionsthe  on error 404.  But I can not find the same one as mine.

I have an application build with ASP.NET MVC 4.  The url routing has not problem at all when I run in Visual Studio 2010.  However when I published the application to Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise server named "MyCompany" under IIS7.5's Default Web Site as an application named "Test", the routing **url misses the application name "Test**".  Thus causes the error 404.

The url is suppossed to be "http://MyCompany/**Test**/Home/Index?fileType=Fin".  However it shows "http://MyCompany/Home/Index?fileType=Fin".

If I deploy the application to different port saying 8080, it works fine with "http://MyCompany:**8080/Test**/Home/Index?fileType=Fin".

Thanks in advance if anyone can help.

My route function is -

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

My WebServer configuration is -

```
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1048576000" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

**Update:**

Robert reminded me of the Javascript potential problem. He is right.  After reviewed my codes again, I found the location of the problem.  This function -

```
function OnChange(dropdown) {
    var myindex = dropdown.selectedIndex;
    top.location.href = "Home/Index?fileType=" + dropdown.options[myindex].value;
    return true;
}
```

should be -

```
function OnChange(dropdown) {
    var myindex = dropdown.selectedIndex;
    top.location.href = "@Url.Content("~/")" +  "Home/Index?fileType=" + dropdown.options[myindex].value;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure Test is set up as an Application and not just a subdirectory?

Comment: @RobertMcKee, I am sure.  It was created as a subdirectory first.  And then I right clicked the folder and converted it to application.  Thanks

Comment: Why do you have `FDICFT` in your "default" route.  I don't see any rules you have set up that should work at all with /Home/Index

Comment: @RobertMcKee, Hi Robert, I have tried different ways since the original way does not work.  The "FDICFT" was "Test". I tried to put the application name in route to see if it works.  Now I have removed it.  It does not work.

Comment: When you say it misses the application name, are you saying that things like @Html.Action doesn't generate the correct URL, or that when you actually type in the URL into the browser it doesn't work?

Comment: If all else fails, delete the application from IIS, create it again and make sure you set it for ASP.NET 4.0, then restart IIS.  The default route you have now is correct.

Comment: @RobertMcKee, Thanks for your help.  But the delete and reinstallation do not work with ASP.NET 4.0.  "@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index")" works fine.  The problem is the controller function " public ActionResult Index(string fileType){ ViewBag.fileType = fileType; return View();}  ".  Default route is fine.  But the second function call just skips the site name "Test" in the URL.  If I manually add the missing site "\Test" in the url, it works fine.

Comment: What second function call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb, and say you've likely hard coded a URL in your javascript instead of using one of the URL building functions.  There are a number of ways around that, but you need to verify that is the case first.  We would need to see the Index view (or the offending javascript file) to see how you are building the URL to be able to determine what exactly is wrong.

Comment: Thanks Robert.  Problem is fixed and the issue is updated with the solution.  It is the Javascript problem! I had overlooked.

Comment: You might want to consider using `top.location.href = "@Url.Action("Index","Home")" + "?fileType=" + dropdown.options[myindex].value` instead.  Even better yet, you might do `"@Url.Action("Index","Home",new {fileType="{0}"})".replace("{0}",dropdown.options[myindex].value)` or similar. Let the framework do the heavy lifting of generating the correct URL as much as possible.  You'll find this handy, especially if you want to change URLs later, do SEO work like enforcing lowercase, etc